# any difference in constructing shared pointer

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, make-shared

what is difference between

```
auto sp = std::make_shared<Foo>();

auto sp(std::make_shared<Foo>());
```

Detailed explanation is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this particular case, there is zero difference. The two declarations are fully equivalent.

---

Now to add a bit more context (assume `T` and `U` are types).

The most general case is this:

```
U makeU();

T direct(makeU());
T copy = makeU();
```

In this case, the first line is *direct initialisation.* `T` needs a constructor which accepts a `U` or something to which `U` can implicitly convert.

The second line is *copy initialisation.* The compiler conceptually rewrites it to mean this:

```
T copy(T(makeU()))
```

That is, a temporary `T` is initialised from the `U` object, and then that temporary `T` is moved (or copied) into `copy`. This means that `T` needs the same constructor as for `direct`, plus an accessible non-explicit copy or move constructor.

A slightly more specialised case happens when `U` is `T`:

```
T makeT();

T direct(makeT());
T copy = makeT();
```

In this case, these two are almost equivalent. Both use the copy/move constructor to initialise the declared `T` from the temporary `T` returned by `makeT`. The only difference is that `direct` will work even if its copy/move constructor is declared `explicit`, while `copy` will error out in such case.

When you replace `T` with `auto` in the variable declarations, you get your original case. And since the copy and move constructors of `std::shared_ptr` are not marked `explicit`, the two lines are fully equivalent.

Comment: then that is not zero difference. the 1st one calls constructor only. the 2nd calls constructor, and the plus(non-explicit copy or move constructor). so the plus is not zero.

Comment: @pepero When `T = U`, the net difference **is** zero. It does not call the copy/move ctor twice.

Answer (score 3):

Since `std::shared_ptr<T>` has an accessible, non-explicit copy constructor there no difference what so ever.

If you generate the assembly code you'll see that for both examples the compiler will generate the same assembly.

**Example #1 (Copy Initialization):**

```
auto sp = std::make_shared<Foo>();
```

[Assembly Code](https://godbolt.org/g/Wgq454)

**Example #2 (Direct Initialization):**

```
auto sp(std::make_shared<Foo>());
```

[Assembly Code](https://godbolt.org/g/UmX8Yx)